How to encrypt partition using LUKS-2?
I have an empty partition (say /dev/sda1) that I want to encrypt with LUKS-2 and be able to open it with passphrase from commonly used file managers (Dolphin, PCManFM-Qt, etc). I prefer a GUI like KDE Partition Manager, but that seems to still use LUKS-1. Is there another GUI partition manager that supports LUKS-2? If not, can someone please give simple step-by-step CLI instructions for that?
I am using Lubuntu 24.04 and Kubuntu 24.04 (multi-boot, so I'm looking for a solution that works in both).

Didn't find a GUI solution. Used commands like the following (found from here) which seem to be working as expected:
Format:
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sda1

Open:
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda1 encrypted

Make file system:
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L enc_part /dev/mapper/encrypted

Verify LUKS version:
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda1

Alternatively, KDE Partition Manager also shows it as luks2.
